# Forcing a one-or-more in the ICollection<> with Entity Framework Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Using Entity Framework 4.1 Code-First, I have set up a many-to-many relationship using the fluent API. If possible, I would like to force one side of the relationship to have 1 or more of the other, instead of the default 0 or more. Currently, if the tables are A and B, A can have 0 or more B's and B can have 0 or more A's, but I would like to force A to have at least 1 B. Can I do this in the data model or do I have to just put it in the business logic?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define this restriction in the model. Probably because you can't define a corresponding foreign key constraint in the database. You could introduce an additional required navigation reference from A to B to ensure that A always refers to at least one B. Table A would need a non-nullable foreign key column to the table B then. But you still had to check in business logic that this required reference is also an element in the collection of the many-to-many relationship (which is not enforced in the database: A (Id=1) could refer to B (Id=2) but there is no entry (1,2) in the join table).